# What is an escape character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string

I would like to split lines which contains [ (bracket: []). However, when I type this as /[/ it is treated as comment.

Comment: What do you mean by "treated as a comment"? It should be treated as an unclosed character class, not as a comment.

Comment: sorry not into comment. You are right. it's unclosed character class.

Comment: Show us your input. What is your example code? Please read "[ask]".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your code and accurately describe the problem.  Include the full error message or incorrect output; "treated as a comment" isn't specific enough to be a problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape the `[` char like `/\[/`.

Answer (score 1):

I infer that you're using `string.split`, which can use a regex (the stuff between the / /) to indicate what delimiter character it will split the string into a list with.

Well, regexes use the [ and ] characters in a special way, to denote that such a group will match any of the characters inside.

[abc] => matches a, b, or c

Since you actually need to match the [ symbol literally, you need to escape it with the \ switch

So, write your split as:

```
string.split(/\[/)
```

Comment: If it's really the case that OP is using `string.split`, he may as well use `string.split('[')` and skip the regex.

Comment: We don't even know what the OP is working with. Without an example of the input data any answer could be encouraging an entirely wrong attempt to do something.